# Можно ли осуществить перенос по строкам внутри <nobr>

Tags: html, css

Есть длинная строка, которая должна переноситься по строкам, но ситуация такова, что она находится внутри тега `<nobr>`, убрать который не представляется возможным. Можно ли каким-либо образом разрешить перенос по строкам с помощью css (у меня по крайней мере не получилось) или единственный вариант - это удалять `<nobr>` с помощью javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
nobr {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <nobr>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</nobr>
</h1>
```